# How to add global parameters to Meteor Iron Router?

Tags: meteor

I can specify a specific route like this in Iron Router

```
Router.path('/:lang/path')
```

and change the language according to the :lang parameter in beforeAction().

How can I do this on a global scale, e.g. every path should have a :lang prefix?

(And yes I know there is the iron-router-i18n package for this, but I cannot use it in my context).

Comment: i believe iron router doesn't have that, but if flow router is an option, that one supports "groups" as they call them, which are shared prefixes for a set of routes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one pattern that might help you do this efficiently:

```
var myRoutes = ['about','info','help','item','post']; // your list of layouts (use your own names)

myRoutes.forEach(function(r){ // create all your routes as /:lang/routeName
  Router.route(':lang/'+r,{ name: r, controller: 'myController' });
});

myController = RouteController.extend({ // define your own controller
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    Session.set('language',this.params.lang); // set the language
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is there are many auto generated routes cerated by other packages.